# How to deal with UUIDS?

Tags: java, mongodb, bigdata, database

The procedure goes like this. I have a set of data which includes URLs, company names and some other info about the companies. I read this data get the URLs crawl them and save the crawled data with a randomly generated UUID.

`UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();`

This is working good for the first round of crawling. The problem is when I want to re-crawl the data again. I will have a new set of data -which might be duplicated- so a new UUID will be generated with a new record. But this is not what I expect. What I would like to do is to see which things that have been crawled and to update them instead of adding new records.
P.S. it's not about reading the URLs and see if the URL is already crawled or not because the company might change its URL or even its name.
So how can I generate these UUIDs? and make sure they are somehow linked to the same -let's say- object so I can update the object (record) instead of having it twice in the database and in my search results.

Comment: You need to compare your new data to your existing data to find out which entry is new and which is supposed to be a change to an existing entry. You simply generate a new UUID without that comparison, do you expect that to happen by itself magically?

Comment: of course not, I don't expect that to happen. If I do I wouldn't even bother asking :/. but as i said `company name and/or url can be changed` so i am looking for a smart solution out there xD .

Comment: You need to think about a way how you can identify if that data has already been saved or not. But with your current description (company name + urls might change) I don't see how that would be possible. How would you **as a human** decide that this data has already been saved if everything about it changed? If you cannot think about a solution for that don't expect a computer to have a magical solution for it.

Comment: You basically want "upserts" where you `$setOnInsert` your UUID field. HOWEVER, as as been pointed out "something else must always be **unique**". i.e the "url" makes the most common sense here. You use that "unique" property as the basis for deciding whether to add a new document or update an existing one ( or even ignore ), But you can't have it both ways.

Comment: If a company can change its name and URL without notifying me, I would have no idea its the same company. I find it hard to believe your code will. Can the IP change, or just the DNS? Either could be considered the only forms of identification.

Comment: Funny thing about companies is that they usually "want to make money". So the usual intent is to make it as easy as possible for people to find them. They will probably use redirects. They will most likely not change domain name at all. In the "edge cases" the former is likely, and the latter would be the most frequent occurrence. You need to pick a logical means. No one will "secretly" hide who they were if it could possibly cost them income. You're overthinking the edge cases and not designing around the common ones. Pick a unique property and stick to it.

Comment: @NeilLunn i don't mean to get out of the context here, but a lot of startups around the globe are changing their names (and they are considered companies) i've seen some real life situations xD.

Comment: Like I said. Edge case. Think about it. If I start business tomorrow with `abc.com` and then one year later I "re-brand" as `xyz.com`. Do I willingly give up all traffic to my former domain? Or do I do something so my existing customers can still find me? It's not your job to work out how to identify a business. It's in their best interests to do that for you.. Going "out of context" is spending any time thinking otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hash of the minimum set of attributes which uniquely and reliably identifies each data item.

You would then persist this hash and on subsequent crawls you pass the received data item into your hashing function and compare the result against your already persisted results. If there's a match then update otherwise insert. This is a crude approximation of the approach but I think you'll get the idea.

The tricky part is identifying which attributes should be included in the hash. Any candidate for inclusion must:

- Be part of the unique key for the data item
- Be immutable

If the URLS are - as you say - mutable then one of the likely candidates is invalid so you'll proabbly have to peek inside the payloads to see if they contain reliable candidates but if these payloads come from numerous, heterogenous sources then you're unlikely to be able to rely on them all conforming to a consistent 'hashing scheme'.

There is no magic solution to this and only you - as the reader of this data - will know what those attributes are since the definition of unique may depend on how you use this data.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but it won't help in my situation. The hash will be linked to some fields (attributes) if one of them is there and matches older record then the item is to be updated, otherwise if everything is changed then the item to be inserted. So the hash wont help because any slight difference would change the whole hash.

Comment: I think that depends on the hashing function. If that function can for any given input reliably generate a value which is - for your purposes - unique then it will allow you to answer this question: 'have I seen this data item before?'. If you can identify the set of attributes which allow you to answer that question then the hashing function is a replacement for your current UUIDs but if you cannot identify this set of fields then no solution ( hashing function or anything else) will allow you to answer that question.